# Htaccess rewrite rule not working when REQUEST_URI does not start with different pattern

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-403

I am trying to redirect any request that does not start with specific patterns.

**For example**

mydomain.com/**test/one**/a

mydomain.com/**test/one**/b

and

mydomain.com/**user/name**/a

mydomain.com/**user/name**/b

So any request that does not match with **mydomain.com/test/one** or **mydomain.com/user/name**  will redirect to some page or web address.

So far i can match following

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/test/one|/user/name) [NC]

RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

so any url started with /test/one or /user/name is redirecting properly.

But when i am trying to **negate the condition with !**  , its redirecting every requests!

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/test/one|/user/name) [NC]

RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

But i want all request to redirect except REQUEST_URI has pattern like
`^(/test/one|/user/name)`

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following htaccess rules file. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Using `THE_REQUEST` variable here for apache to check condition.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/(?:test/one/|user/name/)\S+\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for a `RewriteCond`, just give the pattern to the [`RewriteRule`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), e.g.

```
RewriteRule ^test/one - [F]
RewriteRule ^user/name - [F]
```

This will [forbid](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_f) requests, starting with either `/test/one` or `/user/name`.

---

To rewrite all other requests to some web page, append another `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteRule ^ /some/web/page.html [L]
```

To redirect the client instead of rewriting, add flag [R|redirect](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) to the rule

```
RewriteRule ^ /some/web/page.html [R,L]
```